# Can I convert Bluetooth UUIDs to a manufacturer name?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is there a list of existing, assigned UUID prefixes that would permit me to e.g. recognized that all devices whose UUID begins with 2a299aae are Foobar Inc device?

Comment: I am confused as to what you are asking here. Are you looking for a list of assigned prefixes - or a method to select the UUID's that begin with 2a299aae and then list them as a Foobar Inc Device?

Comment: A list of assigned prefixes

Comment: Are parts of UUIDs assigned similar to Bluetooth addresses?

Answer (score 0):

While there is a mapping of sponsorship for Bluetooth SIG member requested "short" or 16 bit UUIDs, this mapping is related to services rather than hardware devices. I.E., an Intel sponsored UUID does not necessarily mean the device is an Intel device; only that it is using an Intel defined service or protocol.

This link should help (living document): 
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers